# Mocking Library Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I recently started tdd, but my mocking knowledge is incomplete. I know the basics but, Tests for some methods which were written without thinking tdd,  really confuse me.

Here is what I am trying to test

```
public int GetThirdPartyUserId(int serviceTypeId, string accessToken)
{
     ThirdPartyRequestDetail requestDetail = GetThirdPartyRequestDetails(serviceType, accessToken);

     IHttwrapConfiguration configuration = new HttwrapConfiguration(requestDetail.BaseUrl);
     IHttwrapClient httwrap = new HttwrapClient(configuration);

     Task<IHttwrapResponse<OpenAuthUserResponse>> response = httwrap.GetAsync<OpenAuthUserResponse>(requestDetail.PathAndQuery);

      try
      {
          if (response.Result.Data != null && response.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted)
          {
              //Do something
          }
          else
          {
              //WANT TO TEST HERE
          }
      }

}
```

Here is  my test method

```
private Mock<IHttwrapClient> _httpwrap;
public void httprwapTest()
{
    string accessToken = "invalid";
    int thirdPartySiteId = (int)ThirdPartyServiceType.GooglePlus;
    string requestPath = _fixture.Create<string>();

    _httpwrap.Setup(item => item.GetAsync(requestPath)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttwrapResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "body")));            
    OpenAuthUserResponse response = _oauthAuthenticator.GetThirdPartyUser(thirdPartySiteId, accessToken);

    Assert.AreEqual(response.Error, OauthAuthenticatorErrorType.RequestFaulted);

        }
```

What I tried to do is below but it didn't get triggered.

```
_httpwrap.Setup(item => item.GetAsync(requestPath)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttwrapResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "body")));
```

How I can test my classes behaviour when httpwrap gives me a badrequest response code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's current form, you can't use a conventional mocking framework to help with your test.  In order for the Mocking to work, you have to `Setup` the same mock that you're using in your production code.  Currently there's no connection between the mock you're creating in your test and the `IHttpwrapClient` that your method under test depends on.

The first step you would need to do take is to move the creation of the `HttpwrapClient` outside of the method that you want to test.  You then need to make it available to the code, via it's interface, in a way that you can later supply it from your test.

There are three common ways of supplying the interface.

- Inject it into the constructor for your class
- Inject it through a property on your class
- Pass it as an argument to the function

Generally constructor injection is preferred over property injection, but it's largely up to you which approach is going to work best (they each have positives and negatives) and what makes most sense for the data that you're injecting.

You would then create the Mock of your interface and inject it into your code as appropriate.

As far as your production code goes, you're still going to need to create an instance of your concrete class.  You can either do this directly when calling your class, or via something like a factory, or by using an IoC container, like Castle Winsor or Ninject (there are several others).

Comment: I moved the IHttpWrapClient outside of the class as you said then I started mocking that class and everythings worked fine, Thanks